# Learning the basics of JavaScript with a Tetris game

Tags: javascript, beginner, game, tetris

I want to get a better feeling for how JavaScript works and how to use it well. I coded up this Tetris game, and have iterated over the code base and improved it a couple of times now.

I hope the state of the code is fairly good at this point, but also that someone more familiar with the language can suggest further improvements.

I've deliberately avoided the use of any kind of supporting framework to get a feel for JS in general, instead of learning a specific tool.

Game running in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpXtB/).

Minimal HTML that can start the game:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "tetris.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad = "Tetris.init('tetris_canvas');">
  <canvas id = "tetris_canvas" width = "170" height = "300"></canvas>
  <div id = "score"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actual game code:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Tetris game.
 */

var Tetris = (function() {
"use strict";

/**
 * Initialize the game.
 */
function Tetris() {
  var state,
    renderer,
    keyboard,
    gameLoopTimerID;

  var gameLoop = function() {
    if (state.block.replace === true) {
      state.block = new Block(state);
      if (state.gameField.check_direction(state.block)) {
        clearInterval(gameLoopTimerID);
        gameOver();
        this.init(state.canvas_id);
      }
    }

    down.call(this);

    renderer.draw(state);
  };

  var right = function() {
    if (state.block.x < (state.playAreaX - state.block.width())) {
      var hit_something = state.gameField.check_direction(state.block, "r");

      if (!hit_something) {
        state.block.x++;
        renderer.draw(state);
      }
    }
  };

  var left = function() {
    if (state.block.x > 0) {
      var hit_something = state.gameField.check_direction(state.block, "l");

      if (!hit_something) {
        state.block.x--;
        renderer.draw(state);
      }
    }
  };

  var up = function() {
    state.block.orientation += 90;
    if (state.block.orientation >= 360) {
      state.block.orientation -= 360;
    }
    renderer.draw(state);
  };

  var down = function() {
    state.block.down();

    renderer.draw(state);

    clearInterval(gameLoopTimerID);
    gameLoopTimerID = setInterval(
      (function(self) {
        return function() {
          gameLoop.call(self);
        };
      })(this),
      calculate_loop_timer(state.loop_timer, state.level)
    );

  };

  /**
   * Function for decrementing the timer interval as the level goes up.
   * @TODO How expensive is pow()? Could it ever be worthwhile to memoize this?
   */
  var calculate_loop_timer = function(start, level) {
    return start * Math.pow(0.95, level);
  };

  this.init = function(canvas_id) {
    var debug = getUrlVars().debug;

    state = new GameState();
    state.canvas_id = canvas_id;
    renderer = new Canvas_renderer(canvas_id);
    keyboard = new Keyboard();
    document.onkeydown = keyboard.event;

    gameLoopTimerID = setInterval(
      (function(self) {
        return function() {
          gameLoop.call(self);
        };
      })(this),
      state.loop_timer
    );

    if (debug) {
      render_debug_grid();
    }

    // Map keypresses to function calls.
    keyboard.add(keyboard.right, right);
    keyboard.add(keyboard.left, left);
    keyboard.add(keyboard.up, up);
    keyboard.add(keyboard.down, (function(self) {
      return function() {
        down.call(self);
      };
    })(this));
    renderer.draw(state);
  };

  var gameOver = function() {
    alert("Game over\nYour score is: " + state.score.getScore() + "\nPress ok to start a new game");
  };

  var render_debug_grid = function() {
    var t = document.createElement("table"),
      tb = document.createElement("tbody"),
      tr, td,
      y, x;

    for (y = 0; y < state.playAreaY; y++) {
      tr = document.createElement("tr");
      for (x = 0; x < state.playAreaX; x++) {
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x + "," + y));
        td.style.width = "21";
        td.style.height = "23";
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
      tb.appendChild(tr);
    }

    t.style.position = "absolute";
    t.style.fontSize = "10px";

    t.appendChild(tb);

    document.getElementById("debug_grid").appendChild(t);
  };
}

/**
 * Keep track of the games internal state.
 */
function GameState() {
  // Numbers make the layouts much easier to read, therefore relying on JS
  // to cast 0 to false and 1 to true instead of using real booleans.
  this.available_layouts = [
    [
      [0,1,0],
      [1,1,1]
    ], [
      [0,0,1],
      [1,1,1]
    ], [
      [1,0,0],
      [1,1,1]
    ], [
      [0,1,1],
      [1,1,0]
    ], [
      [1,1,0],
      [0,1,1]
    ], [
      [1],
      [1],
      [1],
      [1]
    ], [
      [1,1],
      [1,1]
    ] ];
  // @TODO Improve color selection http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46463/is-there-an-optimum-set-of-colors-for-10-players/46467#46467
  this.layout_colors = [
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 0, 255)",
    "rgb(127, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(127, 127, 0)",
    "rgb(127, 0, 127)",
    "rgb(127, 127, 127)"
  ];

  this.playAreaX = 11;
  this.playAreaY = 20;
  this.blockSize = 15;
  this.block = new Block(this);
  this.gameField = new GameField(this);
  this.score = new Score();

  this.loop_timer = 1000;

  this.removed_lines = 0;

  this.level = 0;

  this.canvas_id = '';
}

function GameField(gameState) {
  var state = gameState,
    gameField = [],
    x, y;

  for (x = 0; x < state.playAreaX; x++) {
    gameField[x] = [];
    for (y = 0; y < state.playAreaY; y++) {
      gameField[x][y] = false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Render the gamefield onto the canvas.
   */
  this.draw = function(ctx) {
    var i, x, y;

    // Clear out the play field.
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, (state.playAreaX * state.blockSize), (state.playAreaY * state.blockSize));

    //Background stripes, mostly for debugging.
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(127, 75, 0, 0.3)";

    for (i = 0; i < (state.playAreaX * state.blockSize); i += state.blockSize * 2) {
      ctx.fillRect(i, 0, state.blockSize, (state.playAreaY * state.blockSize));
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
    for (x = 0; x < state.playAreaX; x++) {
      for (y = 0; y < state.playAreaY; y++) {
        if (gameField[x][y] === true) {
          ctx.fillRect(x * state.blockSize + 1, y * state.blockSize + 1, state.blockSize - 2, state.blockSize - 2);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  /**
   * Check whether the next square in any direction is filled.
   */
  this.check_direction = function(block, direction) {
    var hit_something = false,
      render_offsets = { "x": 0, "y": 0 },
      step, filled,
      render_coord_x, render_coord_y;

    for (step = 0; step < block.width() * block.height(); step++) {
      render_coord_x = state.block.x + render_offsets.x;
      render_coord_y = state.block.y + render_offsets.y;

      switch (direction) {
        case "u": render_coord_y--; break;
        case "r": render_coord_x++; break;
        case "d": render_coord_y++; break;
        case "l": render_coord_x--; break;
      }

      if (gameField[render_coord_x][render_coord_y]) {
        filled = block.piece_filled(step);

        if (filled) {
          hit_something = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      render_offsets = block.update_render_offsets(render_offsets);
    }

    return hit_something;
  };

  /**
   * Check the current position of the active block and take appropriate action.
   * @TODO Function naming doesn't make sense anymore.
   */
  this.check_hit_bottom = function(block) {
    var hit_something = this.check_direction(block, "d"),
      render_offsets, render_coord_x, render_coord_y,
      step, filled;

    if (block.y + block.height() >= gameField[0].length) {
      hit_something = true;
    }

    if (!hit_something) {
      return;
    }

    // The active block has hit something below, and should be pushed to the
    // permanent gamefield.
    block.replace = true;
    render_offsets = { "x": 0, "y": 0 };

    for (step = 0; step < block.width() * block.height(); step++) {
      render_coord_x = block.x + render_offsets.x;
      render_coord_y = block.y + render_offsets.y;

      filled = block.piece_filled(step);

      if (filled) {
        gameField[render_coord_x][render_coord_y] = true;
      }

      render_offsets = block.update_render_offsets(render_offsets);
    }

    this.check_for_full_lines();
  };

  /**
   * Scan a line for it being full. If so remove it.
   *
   * @TODO This logic could be easier if the gamefield array's were inverted,
   * but that might complicate a lot of other logic. Investigate?
   */
  this.check_for_full_lines = function() {
    var full_lines = 0,
      y, x,
      line_piece_count;

    for (y = 0; y < gameField[0].length; y++) {
      line_piece_count = 0;
      for (x = 0; x < gameField.length; x++) {
        gameField[x][y] && line_piece_count++;
      }

      if (line_piece_count === gameField.length) {
        full_lines++;
        for (x = 0; x < gameField.length; x++) {
          gameField[x].splice(y, 1);
          gameField[x].unshift(false);
        }
      }
    }

    if (full_lines > 0) {
      state.score.removed_lines(full_lines);
    }

    state.level += 0.1 * full_lines;
  };
}

function Score() {
  var score = 0,
    line_score = 1000,
    multi_line_bonus = true;

  this.removed_lines = function(num_lines) {
    var bonus = num_lines * line_score;
    if (multi_line_bonus) {
      bonus *= num_lines;
    }
    score += bonus;
  };

  this.draw = function() {
    var score_div = document.getElementById("score");
    if (score_div !== null) {
      score_div.innerHTML = score;
    }
  };

  this.getScore = function() {
    return score;
  };
}

/**
 * Functionality of a single falling tetris block.
 */
function Block(state) {
  this.type = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7) - 1;
  this.color = state.layout_colors[this.type];

  this.orientation = 0;

  var layout = state.available_layouts[this.type];


  this.height = function () {
    if (this.orientation === 0 || this.orientation === 180) {
      return layout.length;
    }
    return layout[0].length;
  };

  this.width = function () {
     if (this.orientation === 90 || this.orientation === 270) {
      return layout.length;
    }
    return layout[0].length;
  };

  this.x = Math.floor(state.playAreaX / 2 - this.width() / 2);
  this.y = 0;

  this.draw = function (ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;

    var render_offsets = { "x": 0, "y": 0 },
      step, filled,
      render_coord_x, render_coord_y;

    for (step = 0; step < this.width() * this.height(); step++) {
      filled = this.piece_filled(step);

      // Render if necessary.
      if (filled) {
        render_coord_x = (this.x + render_offsets.x) * state.blockSize;
        render_coord_y = (this.y + render_offsets.y) * state.blockSize;

        ctx.fillRect(render_coord_x + 1, render_coord_y + 1, state.blockSize - 2, state.blockSize - 2);
      }

      render_offsets = this.update_render_offsets(render_offsets);
    }
  };

  /**
   * The naming and use of this function needs a review.
   */
  this.update_render_offsets = function(render_offsets) {
    render_offsets.x++;

    if (render_offsets.x >= this.width()) {
      render_offsets.y++;
      render_offsets.x = 0;
    }

    return render_offsets;
  };

  /**
   * Figure out if the current piece in a block is filled..
   */
  this.piece_filled = function (step) {
    var coordinates = this.step_to_rotated_coordinates(step),
      filled = layout[coordinates.y][coordinates.x];
    return !!filled;
  };

  /**
   * Converts "search steps" into local x/y coordinates.
   */
  this.step_to_coordinates = function(step) {
    var coords = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    if (this.orientation === 0 || this.orientation === 180) {
      coords.x = step % this.width();
      coords.y = Math.floor(step / this.width());
    }
    else {
      coords.x = Math.floor(step / this.width());
      coords.y = ((step + 1) % this.width());
    }

    return coords;
  };

  /**
   * Converts "search steps" into local x/y coordinates adjusted for piece
   * rotation.
   */
  this.step_to_rotated_coordinates = function(step) {
    var coords = this.step_to_coordinates(step);

    if (this.orientation === 180) {
      coords.x = this.width() - coords.x - 1;
      coords.y = this.height() - coords.y - 1;
    }
    else if (this.orientation === 270) {
      coords.x = this.width() - coords.x;
      // @TODO Ugly hack. Figure out and fix.
      if (this.type === 6) { coords.x--; }
      if (this.width() === 4) { coords.x -= 4; }
      coords.y = this.width() - coords.y - 1;
    }

    return coords;
  };

  this.down = function () {
    state.gameField.check_hit_bottom(state.block, "d");

    if (state.block.replace !== true) {
      this.y += 1;
    }
  };
}

/**
 * Render the game surface on a canvas.
 */
function Canvas_renderer(canvas_id) {
  this.draw = function(state) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    state.gameField.draw(ctx);
    state.block.draw(ctx);
    state.score.draw();
  };
}

/**
 * Keep track of list of keypress to function callback mapping.
 */
function Keyboard() {
  // Make assigning keys easier.
  this.up = 38;
  this.right = 39;
  this.left = 37;
  this.down = 40;

  var callbacks = {};

  //Register a new hook
  this.add = function(key, callback) {
    callbacks[key] = callback;
  };

  // onkeydown callback.
  this.event = function(e) {
    if (callbacks[e.keyCode] === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    callbacks[e.keyCode]();
  };
}

/**
 * Print, debugging tool.
 */
function p(text) {
  var debug_div = document.getElementById("debug_messages");
  if (debug_div !== null) {
    debug_div.innerHTML = text + '<br/> ' + debug_div.innerHTML;
  }
}

function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}

  return new Tetris();
})();
```

Comment: Don't you think there's a little too much code in one file?

Comment: I don't know, is it? Is that a JS idiosyncracy? In other languages I wouldn't expect anyone to say that off 500 - 600 lines of code. Do you have specific suggestions for how to split it up?

Comment: Well, JS isn't a verbose language like Java. You usually start wondering how to split up objects responsibilities (or "modules") around 100 lines or so (or even before).

Comment: Well, it seems to be cleanly broken up into a couple isolated components already. Keeping them all in one file seems like no biggie unless you think that it will encourage hidden dependencies.

Comment: I would generally split it up into a couple .js files and call them from the `<head>`.

Comment: The code lines shouldn't be a problem when you minify and compress (you are doing that right?). Also don't split your files because that increases HTTP requests which slows loading time. You can understand this better by reading: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#external
 Notice how http requests is the first thing on their list.

Comment: I'm aware the code should be minified and compressed, but I'm hardly releasing this code onto the world. There are enough tetris clones out there already, most of them significantly better than this. I'm more concerned with code than loading time, here. :) I guess I should take the lack of answers as a sign that there's aren't any large obvious issues with it.

Comment: @Letharion You should take the lack of answers as a sign that there is too much code to review. Take a Sample section of it and ask for a review on that. Then Alter your code accordingly. Rinse and repeat with a new question and new section until you are happy it is clean.

Answer (score 3):

From a one-time reading:

- Functions `left`, `right`, `up` and `down` do model changes and deal with the view. Ideally, you would have a controller functionality that calls those functions when required, and afterwards the controller can then call `renderer.draw(state)`.
- I don't think you have to memoize `pow()`.
- Magic numbers are present in `render_debug_grid`.  I am guessing those values ought to be based on `blockSize`.
- For initializing, if you are willing to deal with falsey values, you could just create the x arrays, and treat undefined as false, or otherwise you could create a y array and `slice` it x times.
- I think the code would be cleaner if `check_direction` was called with the offsets straight away instead of deriving them from u/r/d/l.
- There is some copy-pasted code in `check_hit_bottom` and `check_direction`, which you could make DRY'er.
- As per your comment, it is not clear for the casual reader what function `update_render_offsets` does, nor any other function under it in `Block`.